# How to redirect www.sub.domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Let's say I have `www.subdomain.domain.com/anything`
I want to redirect to `www.domain.com/anything`  in .htaccess.

Cannot find anything on the topic.

What would be a correct rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.domain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Addition or removal of `www` prefix at your own discretion.